# A setup package is either missing or damaged [Azure DevOps Server 2019]

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I'm setting up a Azure DevOps server, and want to install it my device.

This problem popped up when I tried to install Azure DevOps Server:

> A setup package is either missing or damaged [Azure DevOps Server
>   2019]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> A setup package is either missing or damaged [Azure DevOps Server 2019]

You can download the full ISO for Azure DevOps Server:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

[image]

Then according the document [Install on a single server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/single-server?view=azure-devops) to install Azure DevOps Server.

Hope this helps.